# How to make my live chart load in Ionic from html5 iframe

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an Android app with Ionic, it is a forex signal app, in one of the pages, I placed a widget I got from investing.com, the widget is supposed to give me live chart that updates every minute and its being loaded in an iframe, now my problem is that, the live chart is displaying but its but updating, like the chart is not changing, it's just static.

Here is my code

```
<ion-content>
    <iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden; display:block; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%" src="https://sslcharts.forexprostools.com/index.php?force_lang=1&pair_ID=1&timescale=300&candles=50&style=candles"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

But if I should load the page in a normal html page, the chart won't be static. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Since its iframe then we cant controll it well so instead of src use [src]="frame" and in ts add frame:string="your link"  set an interval in constructor for every one minute and in interval you do thus.frame=""; then this.frame="your link" but i think this will cause iframe to reload and this will be bad but check it anyway

Comment: Tips for posting: try to use real English words. That's pretty easy if you install a spell-checker into your browser (most have at least one installed by default). Words like "pls" are not necessary, since the time saved not typing a few letters is trivial, and Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. When referring to yourself ("I") this requires a capital letter. Again, a spell-checker should catch that. Try to refrain from "please help me", "urgent" and other forms of begging; technical writing is preferred.

Comment: It is worth noting that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to collect good-quality questions and answers that will be useful to many programmers in the future. Thus, readability and effort is important. Good luck with your future questions!